# How to prove the 2nd & 3rd conditions of outer measure?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I have this question on outer measure from Richard Bass' book:

> Prove that $\mu^*$ is an outer measure, given a measure space $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ and define
>
> $$\mu^*(A) = \inf \{\mu(B) \mid A \subset B, B \in \mathcal A\}$$
>
> for all subsets $A$ of $X$.

Here are what I have gone so far:

(1) The first condition is the easiest one: 
$$\begin{align}
\mu^*(\emptyset) &= \inf \{\mu(B) \mid \emptyset \subset B, B \in \mathcal A\}\\
&= \mu (\emptyset) \\
&= 0
\end{align}$$

(2) Now the second condition. Let $D, E \in X$ and $D \subset E$,
$$\begin{align}
\mu^*(D) &= \inf \{\mu(D') \mid D \subset D', D' \in \mathcal A\}\\
\mu^*(E) &= \inf \{\mu(E') \mid E \subset E', E' \in \mathcal A\}\\
\end{align}$$
Here I need to prove $\mu^* (D) \leq \mu^*(E)$. It looks to me so intuitive especially if I draw Venn diagrams of $D, E, D'$ and $E'$, but I don't know how to say it in math-speak. I would appreciate helps on this 2nd. condition.

(3) And this 3rd. condition is my major stumbling block: Given $(A_i)_{i \in \mathbb N} \subset X$, I need to arrive at

$$\mu^* (\bigcup _{i=1}^{\infty} A_i)\leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu^* (A_i).$$

Here, I know for sure I need to  state this first: $\forall A_i, \exists B_i $ such that $ A_i \subset B_i, B_i \in \mathcal A$, but I don't think the next step is right:

$$\begin{align}
\mu^*(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i) &= \inf \{\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(B_i) \mid A_i \subset B_i, B_i \in \mathcal A\}\\
&= \ldots\\
\end{align}$$

I would appreciate any help on this 3rd. condition in addition to the 2nd. above. Thank you for your time and effort.

---

**POST SCRIPT:** After I posted this question, I found this proposition on the same text, perhaps this proposition holds key to the solution, in that I don't have to prove the 2nd and 3rd conditions? Thanks again.

> **Proposition**: Suppose $\mathcal C$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ such that $\emptyset$ and $X$ are both in $\mathcal C$. Suppose $\mathscr l : \mathcal C \to [0, \infty]$ with $\mathscr l (\emptyset) = 0$. Define
>
> $$\mu^* (E) = \inf \{ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathscr l (A_i) \mid A_i \in \mathcal C \text{ for each } i, \text{and }  E \subset \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \}.$$
>   Then $\mu^*$ is an outer measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see how the quoted proposition helps, although I may be missing something. Nonetheless, the exercise is easy to solve without it.

(2) Since $D\subset E$, $X_E:=\{E'\in\mathcal A\ :\ E\subset E'\}\subset X_D:=\{D'\in\mathcal A\ :\ D\subset D'\}$, so the infimum over the elements of $X_E$ is larger than the infimum over $X_D$. In other words,
$$
\mu^*(E)=\inf_{B\in X_E}\{\mu(B)\}\ge\inf_{B\in X_D}\{\mu(B)\}=\mu^*(D).
$$

(3) Let $(A_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}\subset X$. By definition of $\mu^*$, for each $\varepsilon>0$ and $n\in\mathbb N$, there exists $B_n\in\mathcal A$, $B_n\supset A_n$, such that
$$
\mu(B_n)<\mu^*(A_n)+\frac\varepsilon{2^n}.
$$
Then $\bigcup_nB_n\in\mathcal A$ and $\bigcup_nB_n\supset\bigcup_nA_n$, so again by definition of $\mu^*$,
$$
\mu^*\left(\bigcup_nA_n\right)
\le\mu\left(\bigcup_nB_n\right)
\le\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\mu\left(B_n\right)
<\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\mu^*\left(A_n\right)+\varepsilon,
$$
and you conclude since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it enhanced my knowledge, you have earned my up-vote and green check mark. I came up with my own solution at the same time I received yours, which I posted below. Do you think my logic make sense? I am curious to know, and to learn. I value yours for its elegance and brevity, but mine only for its originality (but clumsy and folksy.) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

At the same time I received response from @Ian, I came up with my own solution, I am posting it here to let others see if its logic makes sense. If it does, then I would value @Ian's for its elegance and brevity, and mine for its originality (but folksy and clumsy.) Thanks again to @Ian for responding.

---

Here is my solution after some changes per @Ian's correction (see comment below):

(1) The firs condition:
$$\begin{align}
\mu^*(\emptyset) &= \inf \{\mu(B) \mid \emptyset \subset B, B \in \mathcal A\}\\
&= \mu (\emptyset) \\
&= 0
\end{align}$$

(2) The second condition: Let $D, E \subset X$ and $D \subset E$, then

$$\begin{align}
\mu^* (D) &= \inf \{ \mu (D') \mid D \subset D', D' \in \mathcal A\}, 
\\
\mu^* (E) &= \inf \{ \mu (E') \mid E \subset E', E' \in \mathcal A\}.
\end{align}$$

From $D \subset E$ we need to show that 
$$\inf\{\mu (D') \mid D' \in \mathcal A, D \subset D'\} \leq \inf \{\mu(E') \mid E'\in \mathcal A, E \subset E'\}.$$
Suppose that by way of contraidiction, $D \subset E$ leads to $\inf \{\mu (D')\} > \inf \{\mu (E')\}$ instead. But this contradicts the definition of $D′$ being the infimum of all sets belong to $\mathcal A$ and containing $D$. Therefore $D \subset E$ has to lead to $\inf\{\mu (D′)\}\leq \inf \{\mu (E′)\}$.

Hence $\mu^* (D) \leq \mu^* (E)$.

(3) The third condition: Let $(A_i)_{i \in \mathbb N} \subset X$, and  $(B_i)_{i \in \mathbb N} \in \mathcal A.$

$$\begin{align}
\text{Given } \mu^* (A_i) &= \inf \{\mu(B_i) \mid A_i \subset B_i, B_i \in \mathcal A\}, \\
\text{therefore, } \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu^* (A_i) &= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\inf \{\mu(B_i) \mid A_i \subset B_i, B_i \in \mathcal A\}.\\
\text{On the other hand, } \ \mu^* (\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i) &= \inf \{\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} B_i) \mid \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} B_i, B_i \in \mathcal A\}.\\
\end{align}$$

CASE-1: If $B_i$'s are pairwise disjoint, that is $B_i \cap B_j = \emptyset$ for all $i, j \in \mathbb N$, then
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu^* (A_i) = \mu^* (\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i).$$

CASE-2: If $B_i \cap B_j \neq \emptyset$ for certain $i, j \in \mathbb N$, then
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu^* (A_i) < \mu^* (\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i).$$

Therefore for all cases

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu^* (A_i) \leq \mu^* (\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i),$$

hence $\mu^*$ is an outer measure. $\qquad \blacksquare$

Comment: Hi A.Magnus. Thanks for posting your answer, it will surely be useful for future users. There are some imprecisions. First in (2), you are implicitly assuming that the infimum is attained, i.e. that there exists $E'$ s.t. $\mu^*(E)=\mu(E')$, but I'm sure you know that an infimum is not necessarily attained! In (3), your definition of $\mu^* (\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i)$ does not make sense since the union of measures is not defined. You should write $\mu^* (\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i):=\inf\{\mu(B)\ :\ \bigcup_iA_i\subset B,\ B\in\mathcal A\}$, and then the rest does not make sense...

Comment: Thanks! I will stick to yours, I suffer from bruised ego but that is the price of learning :-) Thanks again.